# Rails Form using Foundation: adding placeholder text

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm using Foundation for my Rails forms and using the directions: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html

I can't get the placeholder text to show.

My view code:

```
<div class="field">
  <h2>Personal Information</h2>
  <%= f.label :full_name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :full_name, placeholder="Please enter first last and initial."%>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be doing like this `placeholder:` not `placeholder=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag) for the Rails way. Rails input fields do not have the same syntax as HTML tags. You have a couple options, either:

```
<%= f.text_field :full_name, placeholder: "Please enter first last and initial" %>
```

or

```
<%= f.text_field :full_name, :placeholder => "Please enter first last and initial" %>
```

Comment: Nice, that worked! Thanks for the help! (new programmer here).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Justin's answer a little, keep in mind that everything between ERB's `<% %>` tags is Ruby.

While at first it might feel like the Ruby ends at `full_name`, what's you're really doing is calling a method with arguments:

```
f.text_field(:full_name, placeholder: "Please enter first last and initial.")
```